# How to create a csv with lat long coordinates from a WGS84 layer with Grass

Tags: grass-gis, csv, latitude-longitude, wgs84

This question seems trivial but I'm having trouble doing this simple task.
I'm working on a WGS84 location in Grass 6.4 and I'm trying to convert a raster layer in a csv with lat long coordinates using r.out.xyz but all I can get is a list of longitudes that range from 180.25 to 539.75 and latitudes from -55.75 to 83.75.
I need them to range from -180 to 180 and from -90 to 90.
r.info output:

> Type of Map:  raster               Number of Categories: 255
>   | |   Data Type:    DCELL
>   | |   Rows:         294
>   | |   Columns:      720
>   | |   Total Cells:  211680
>   | |        Projection: Latitude-Longitude
>   | |            N:     89:06N    S:     58:06S   Res: 0:30:02.44898
>   | |            E:       180E    W:       180W   Res:  0:30

g.region -p

> projection: 3 (Latitude-Longitude)
>   zone:       0 
>   datum:      wgs84
>   ellipsoid:  wgs84
>   north:      89:30N
>   south:      58:30S
>   west:       180E
>   east:       180E
>   nsres:      0:30
>   ewres:      0:30

Comment: I solved it with g.region n=90 s=-90 w=-180 e=-180.